# NoReverseMatch at /courses/course/1/1/

Tags: python, django

I was editing the template to include a hyperlink. But when I do I get NoReverseMatch error.

Reverse for 'views.hello_world' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

The template file:

layout.html

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/layout.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

<div class="site-container">
    <nav>
        <a href="{% url 'views.hello_world' %}">Home</a> [**Error here**]
    </nav>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^courses/', include('courses.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.hello_world)
]
urlpatterns+=staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def hello_world(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

The line,
    Home
when removed I don't get any error. But I add, the NoReverseMatch arises. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which Django version are you using? Is this your root `urls.py`?

Comment: I am using django version 1.10.1. And yes this is my root url. i.e. one inside the same 'project name' folder django makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the URL a name, and refer to that name in the url tag.

```
url(r'^$', views.hello_world, name='hello_world')
```

...

```
<a href="{% url 'hello_world' %}">
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks! Is this a new provision in django 1.10.1? Because I'm following a tutorial, and it worked fine in django version 1.6 or something.

Comment: Yes, because 1.10 removed the ability to use string paths in urls.py.

Comment: Ok so you mean whenever I used strings paths before 1.10, I have to refrence the url by proving name now onwards?